# Delete attributes from an enum class in python

Tags: python-3.x, enums

Can i override the **delattr** or **setattr** to try to delete or disable some attributes of a an enum class, ex:

```
Class example(int, Enum):
     S1 = 1
     S2 = 2
     S3 = 3

  def __delattr__():
      # as default, we cannot delete an attribute like S3 from the enum class, but if
      #possible
      # i want this to remove S3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, to do so in my use case, it is better to work with cycle structure, provide the updated list and remember the last element in a global variable

```
import itertools

List = itertools.cycle(Updatedlist)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete attributes from Enums by default because you are not supposed to.

Enums are meant to 'provide a set of symbolic names bound to unique, constant values'

They are meant to be defined within your program and treated as constants.

It's bad practise and can lead to errors where the program expects the existence of that attribute but finds nothing.

Also, please provide some context so we can help suggest alternative methods

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i am aware of that behavior but in my use case the enum could extend its elements (with the aid of extend_enum function from aenum library) what i want is to be able to delete an element as well. The idea basically to have a dynamic enum as basis for the RoundRobin algorithm